# Why do inner joins result in cross joins sometimes?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle v11.2 with sqlplus.

I have a table that is the lap times of a high school track team. The table is

```
                                  track.laptimes

Name                                                  Null?    Type
----------------------------------------------------- -------- ----------------
MATCHID                                                NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
PLAYERID                                              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
LAP                                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
POSITION                                                       NUMBER(10)
```

I'm trying to return a single table with 3 columns, the lap, and the position of the first(mike) and second place winner(bob) for a particular matchID which has 20 laps. For the example we can hard code the first place being

```
PLAYERID=1 as mike
```

and second being

```
PLAYERID=2 as bob
```

An expected result when querying matchID=1 would be

```
     lap          mikePos        bobPos                                    
    ------------ -------- -------------------
     1             3                7
     2             2                4
     ........
     20            1                2
```

I can get half of the query no problem

```
SELECT laptimes.lap, laptimes.position AS mikePos
FROM track.laptimes
WHERE matchID=1 AND playerID=1;
```

This results in more than 20 rows though and doesn't have the appropriate 3rd column.

The problem arises when I attempt to add another column to this output for bob's position within the same match and for the same lap. How should I approach this? I tried doing an INNER JOIN and using a WITH clause but I keep resulting in a CROSS JOIN giving me 400 rows instead of the desired 20. Could someone point me in the right direction on how I might structure this query?

My thought was to have two tables similar to the above query but one for mike and one for bob then join them back to the tracks.laptimes table and select the lap, mikePos and bobPos but I have had no luck doing it this way and always results in a CROSS JOIN.

I'm not looking for the answer just a point in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join on the matchid, lap and the player, assuming matchid and playerid and lap is the primary key.

```
SELECT a.lap, a.position AS mikePos, b.position as bobpos
FROM track.laptimes a
    inner join track.laptimes b on a.matchid=b.matchid and b.playerid=2 and a.lap=b.lap
WHERE a.matchid=1 AND a.playerID=1
```

Comment: Thank you! I was failing to use the ON clause properly.